# SQL column names in Groovy JDBC app?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, groovy

We access a SQL Server database using JDBC in a Groovy program.

We execute a query and are trying to determine the column names of the output using code like this:

```
result = sql.rows(query)
{
  meta ->
   colNames = (1..meta.columnCount).collect
   { meta.getColumnName(it) }
   colTypes = (1..meta.columnCount).collect
   { meta.getColumnTypeName(it) }
   colNull  = (1..meta.columnCount).collect
   { meta.isNullable(it) }
   colAuto  = (1..meta.columnCount).collect
   { meta.isAutoIncrement(it) }
}
```

Problem is, with certain queries, the getColumnName() function returns nulls. For example, a query like this: `select name, type_name(user_type_id), max_length from sys.parameters where object_id = object_id('some procedure name')` always returns null for the second column.

We checked "getColumnLabel()" it seems to give us the same value as "getColumnName()".

Short of cooking up our own scheme, is there a recommended way to generate column names when getColumnName() returns null?

This is Ubuntu 15.04, Java 1.8.0_45, Groovy 1.8.6, SQLJDBC42 and SQL Server 2014.

Comment: sys.parameters is a dynamic view for the objects parameters. For e.g. paremeters of a stored procedure. What column names do you want to generate? for a table?

Comment: That's just an example. The problem is the "type_name(user_type_id)" in this case...it returns null (as do any similarly computed columns on any table)

Comment: type_name() returns NULL on error or if a caller does not have permission to view the object. Check it out. See this ref also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189750.aspx

Comment: There is no column name (or label) in your query: add an `AS` clause or live with it and use the index instead.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: Yes, you're correct there's no specific label in this query - that's the problem we're trying to address (the user generates queries - we can't control them, but want to correctly label the output). This same query on other databases returns "type_name(user_type_id)" as the label from getColumnLabel(), as does Microsoft's command-line query tool when we run this same query. Showing a column-name of "unlabeled" seems weak to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can put below queries in programmable objects with parameters (schema,objName) to list columns for a table or view.

```
--get the columns of a table
select c.name
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = 'Person' and t.schema_id = schema_id('Person');

--get the columns of a view
select c.name
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.views t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = 'vEmployee' and t.schema_id = schema_id('dbo');
```

Comment: No, the problem is we need to execute arbitrary queries and get the column names - we can't control the query. If we could, we'd just do "xxxxx AS Name" (this returns "Name" in getColumnName).

Answer (score 0):

In your query as it stands right now, your second column has no name. You need to give it an alias name as follows:

```
select name, type_name(user_type_id) AS whatever, max_length from sys.parameters where object_id = object_id('some procedure name')
```

Then the name of your second column will show up as `whatever`.